# Vue Mixin computed function pass parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I wan't to be able to use my mixin just like the vue [i18next](https://github.com/panter/vue-i18next) library uses `$t`

```
<div>
      <strong>{{ $t("loadbundle", {lang: this.lang}) }}</strong>
</div>
```

and I can tell in the source code that it is a computed property in a mixin

```
  Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
      $t() {
        const getKey = getByKey(this._i18nOptions, this.$i18n ? this.$i18n.i18next.options : {});

        if (this._i18nOptions && this._i18nOptions.namespaces) {
          const { lng, namespaces } = this._i18nOptions;

          const fixedT = this.$i18n.i18next.getFixedT(lng, namespaces);
          return (key, options) => fixedT(getKey(key), options, this.$i18n.i18nLoadedAt);
        }

        return (key, options) =>
          this.$i18n.i18next.t(getKey(key), options, this.$i18n.i18nLoadedAt);
      },
    }
```

but I can't figure out how he made it possible to call it like a function and how does he get the parameters passed in.

I can't use a method because they get executed every time something updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the `return (key, options) => ...` bit: that returns a function!
So the template invocation you wrote above first retrieves the value of the computed property (a function) and then invokes it with some parameters.

Effectively, all the up-front preparation of grabbing the `$i18n` object is done once, but the translation can still change if any of the parameters change (for example `this.lang`).